# DOS output last modified of directory to file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a directory of files that I need to check the last modified Date of and put that result into a file. I need this to be a batch file and I need the output file to be easily readable

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service where you post your list of requirements and someone writes the code for you. If you need that service, hire a contractor. We're glad to help if you try to write something yourself and run into problems, but you must make some effort to do this first and post your code. There are many posts here about batch file programming and dealing with files by date. Some time searching here would get you started, and then if you run into a problem you can post a specific question here (along with the code you've written) and we can try and help you. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for letting me know why I was being down voted. I've actually done this before and have been searching my computer extensively for my previous work without success but I though this would be fairly simple, I apologize for 'write my code' attitude tho. okay more specifically I have this: dir "c:/myfolder/" /S /O:d > "c:/myfolder/dos_output.txt" which seems to work

Comment: if you want to do more then just find the last modified date you can look at the answer I suggested which utilises the `forfiles` command. Type `forfiles /?` to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Easy :

```
forfiles /p [path to file] /c "cmd.exe /c echo @file : @fdate"
```

There are many similar questions to this already on stackoverflow, so next time look at these and try interpreting them.

Hope this helped,

Yours Mona.

Comment: You've just removed all reason for the poster to search first, as you've provided an answer for them. If you know there are duplicates, perhaps you could post a comment instead that links one of those duplicates instead, instead of supplying yet another one here. (You know how to post comments - you've already posted a comment to make sure the poster saw your answer.)

Comment: @KenWhite I was simply recommending him to search up his question thoruoghly before he asked a question for good practice.

Comment: I know. My point was that you just took away all reason for him to do so by answering. Now in the future, he's encouraged to just post a question without searching, knowing that someone will say "Here's the answer. Next time you should search.". If you know of a duplicate, direct him to the duplicate in a comment (until you have earned enough privileges to vote to close as a duplicate, when you can do that instead.)

Answer (score 0):

dir "c:/myfolder/" /S /O:d > "c:/myfolder/dos_output.txt"